# Множественное добавление торговых предложений

Tags: html, битрикс

Стоит задача сделать возможность добавить несколько торговых предложений в корзину, у которых проставлено количество по клику на кнопку.
На одном из форумов я выяснил что это не сложно сделать, но видимо я пока не в состоянии самостоятельно сделать.

"Суть примерно такая - в карточке вам надо что-то типа списка чекбоксов с ID товаров для добавления в корзину -

```
<input type='checkbox' name='product[]' value='1'>
```

А на странице, обрабатывающий `SUBMIT` кнопки покупки, пройти по `$_REQUEST['product'] и сделать Add2BasketByProductID.`

```
int Add2BasketByProductID( $PRODUCT_ID, $QUANTITY = 1, $arRewriteFields = array(), $arProductParams = false);
```

Функция добавляет в корзину товар с кодом `PRODUCT_ID` в количестве `QUANTITY` единиц (по умолчанию одну штуку) и возвращает код позиции товара в корзине. Функция является оберткой над `CSaleBasket::Add`, но при этом размещена в модуле Торгового каталога."

Из всего этого все что смог понять понял и вот что получилось:

```
<form action="<?=$_REQUEST['id']?>" method="post">
    <input type='checkbox' name="id" value='152'>
    <input type='checkbox' name="id" value='153'>
    <input type='checkbox' name="id" value='154'>

    <input  type="text" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity"> 
    <a  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BX('quantity').value++;">+</a> 
    <a  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity').value > 1) BX('quantity').value--;">-</a> 

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY">

    <input type="submit" value="КУПИТЬ" name="Add2BasketByProductID">
</form>
```

Выбираю все чекбоксы, кликаю по сабмит и у меня в корзину падает только первый элемент с id 152.
Не исключаю что я вообще не так все понял из совета, подскажите что я не так делаю?

Comment: хоть советом помогите!

Comment: Удалите свои ответы. И отметьте правильный галочкой — напротив ответа.

Comment: Поделитесь решением, как вы реализовали обработку запроса? плиз...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляется только первый выбранный товар из-за того что в обработчик формы приходит только одно значение «id» из-за того что чекбосы имеют один параметр name и не являются масивом.
Для решения задачи форма должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type='checkbox' name="product_id[]" value='152'>
            <input type="text" name="quantity_152" value="1" id="quantity"> 


        <input type='checkbox' name="product_id[]" value='153'>
            <input type="text" name="quantity_153" value="1" id="quantity"> 


        <input type='checkbox' name="product_id[]" value='154'>
            <input type="text" name="quantity_154" value="1" id="quantity"> 


        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY">
        <input type="submit" value="КУПИТЬ" name="Add2BasketByProductID">
    </form>
    <?if(isset($_REQUEST["product_id"]) && CModule::IncludeModule("sale") && CModule::IncludeModule("catalog")){
        foreach($_REQUEST['product_id'] as $PRODUCT_ID){
            $quantity = 1;
            if((int)$_REQUEST['quantity_'.(int)$PRODUCT_ID] > 1)
                 $quantity = (int)$_REQUEST['quantity_'.(int)$PRODUCT_ID];
            Add2BasketByProductID( (int)$PRODUCT_ID, $quantity);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Т.е. инпут типа чекбокс становится массивом, но битрикс не сможет сам обработать значения этого поля — придётся писать свой обработчик.
Предлагаю сделать страницу «multi-buy-ajax.php». И отправлять результат формы на эту страницу.

На этой странице Вам понадобится разобрать массив $_POST["id"]  и вызвать для каждого значения функцию

```
Add2BasketByProductID( $PRODUCT_ID, $QUANTITY = 1, $arRewriteFields = array(), $arProductParams = false);
```

Comment: В форме `action` оставить пустым

Comment: Дополнил код в ответе — проверьте

Comment: Количество указывается верно?

Comment: Ну Вы же используете в коде количество и получается по Ваашему коду — передаёте количество 0

Comment: т.е. заработало?

Comment: Сейчас создам тестовый магазин.

Comment: Обновил код. Работоспособность можно проверить http://1036lab.bitrixlabs.ru/catalog/t-shirts/t-shirt-mens-purity/

Comment: Получилось всё?